# How do you make a template for screens in ScreenManager?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I was wondering how you make a template for screens in kivy using ScreenManager.

I want to be able to have a template that will create screens with a grid layout in which I can change the background image of the screen and add a label and button to it.

I tried using

```
[ScreenMenu@BoxLayout]:
    Button:
        text: ctx.title
Image:
    source: ctx.image
```

And then using

```
screen1 = Builder.template('ScreenMenu', title='Hello', image='C:/Users/mmoma_000/Pictures/Wallpapers/aot.png')
```

But I can't access the screens it makes (if it even successfully makes a screen) 
I assume I will need to do something about adding the widgets to screen manager but I'm not sure what that is.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are deprecated, don't use them, use dynamic classes instead.

I don't know exactly what your problem is though. Are you using Builder in the kv file or in python?

Of course, you could also solve the problem by just using a normal class.